# CefSharp setEmulatedMedia

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp.offscreen

I am trying to get my browser to create a screen like pdf. My code, based on MinimalExample.Offscreen works but generates the print image version, which is the default. I know this can be done because pupeteer does it if you are in a node.js enviroment.

I am using:

```
 var scriptTask = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("Emulation.setEmulatedMedia({ media: 'screen'});");
```

I've tried a few variations but I'm not getting it right. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you open Chrome and run the same JavaScript in devtools?